# Is it a standard practice of tenure and promotion committee to ask for review reports of some published papers of the one evaluated?

Tags: publications, peer-review, tenure-track

Is it a standard practice for tenure and promotion committee to ask for referee reports of some published papers of the one evaluated?

Comment: Right to what? There are no laws keeping journal article referee reports private or anonymous. This is only done by convention.

Comment: I have never heard of it.  Is this a hypothetical question, or is this happening to you?  If the latter, maybe you should clarify the country and whether the committee asks this of everyone going up for tenure or just some people.

Comment: Does this not violate confidentiality?

Comment: @Kimball This is merely a hypothetical question.

Comment: Maybe it does, but there's no law giving that confidentiality. Also, maybe it doesn't. Single-blind reviews are anonymous to allow reviewers to speak their minds without fear of reprisal. Double-blind reviews are blind to fight bias among reviewers based on the authors' identities. Revealing the contents of reports after the fact, especially for accepted articles doesn't affect either of these issues.

Comment: Sometimes reviewers' reports are even [published](http://retractionwatch.com/2014/09/11/potentially-groundbreaking-highly-provocative-nature-stap-cell-peer-reviews-published/) by the journal.

Comment: @BillBarth I was just checking the links you provided and at the end of the email from Nature with the reviews there is a clear note stating: "This email is confidential and subject to copyright" (http://news.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/NATURE%20REVIEWS.pdf) so I guess one could say that at least in some cases there might be some (copyright) laws involved.

Comment: @Miguel, yes, I assume that Nature published those reports with the reviewers' express permission or just assumed they had a fair use right to them. In the case user describes, I would guess that some reviewer somewhere might try to sue over the copying of their report in the reviewee sharing it with their tenure committee. I don't think the suit would be likely to win because there are lots of defenses available. Also, Nature can assert that it's confidentiality, but that doesn't make it so. Plus, there's no law that I know of that would help them if someone breached the confidentiality.

Answer (score 12):

My university (a private R1) does ask for **referee/reader reports** in the case of newly published material in tenure and promotion cases. This is done when the scholar has  recently published material that has not been cited elsewhere (thus, no bibliometric citation data) and the committee wants to ascertain the contribution to the field of study that the text may make.

Assuming your publication was accepted, you should view this as a good thing. Referee reports in those circumstances are positive, highlighting the contribution you are making to the field (otherwise, why would the journal publish it?). Folks on tenure and promotion committees also know to read through the negative cruft on reader's reports, so don't worry about that issue either.

p.s. I should note that at my university (as well as others), there is pushback against the use of pure bibliometric data (impact factors) as a way to ascertain a scholar's prominence in the field, but that is another question.

Answer (score 7):

**Review reports** as in your title: yes.  Asking an outside expert in the field for comments about the published work of the candidate.  This is standard practice in some places and in some fields.

**Referee reports** as in the question: I have not heard of that.  Except maybe in the case of a paper that has been accepted but not yet published: the referee report or editor's letter may be used as evidence of the acceptance.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a committee expecting candidates to preserve the referee reports of previously published papers. I delete the referee reports from my mail box as soon as a paper is published.

They can ask, however, the acceptance letters of the papers listed in your CV as *accepted for publication* but not yet actually published. In case you don't provide the acceptance letters, the committee might not (or *will* not, depending on the country, institution etc.) consider those publications in the evaluation process.